# String to hex base 16 in python 3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

How can I convert a string into a hex?

I have this text from a .csv `\\302\\247\\303\\277\\001\\036\\303\\211\\000n\\`

and I want to convert to something like `0x394839F`

My first attempt was use `bytearray` but don't work

Comment: How do the numbers in the example text relate to the desired result?

Comment: What is the connection between the string `"\\302\\247\\303\\277\\001\\036\\303\\211\\000n\\"` and the number `0x394839F`? If you can describe the process in words, then try to translate the words into Python code. If you're having trouble with that last part, feel free to ask about a *specific problem* while providing a [mcve] and you will get much better responses.

Comment: @trentcl the number 0x394839F is aleatory, I wrote just to make a example how I desire my output

Comment: @wwii they are just for representation, just an example.

Comment: If not `0x394839F`, what number *do* you expect to get from the example input? There's no *one* way to convert a string to a number, like there's no *one way* to make a car; it depends on your needs. If you can't communicate to *us* what conversion procedure you want to follow, how will you make a dumb old computer understand it?

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess what is asked, but it seems to me you have a list of octal numbers '\xxx' and want to convert them to hex.

Python has all you need - `split` for splitting the input, `int` for converting from octal, `format` for emitting a value in hex a finally `join` to glue the small pieces into one string. Just combine them.

```
IN = '\\302\\247\\303\\277\\001\\036\\303'

print("0x" + "".join("{:02X}".format(int(n,8)) for n in IN.split('\\') if n))
```

This will not handle "\000n", it looks like a typo.